# p-values for feature selection

Tags: anova, multiple-regression, p-value, feature-selection

I am doing multiple regression analysis, in which i want to eliminate some of the insignificant features.  In most of the machine learning books subset selection, shrinkage methods or PCA is used for reducing number of feature.  Why p-values are not commonly used for feature selection?

Comment: [This is why.](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/20856/1352) (Whether you do it in a stepwise manner or all at once doesn't change the fundamental problem.)

Comment: @Stephan : I read the answer. Does it imply p-values should never be used?

Comment: No. You can use and interpret p values if you use them correctly. [This is a good place to start understanding them](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value?sort=votes&pageSize=50). In your specific case, if you look at multiple models (by selecting features), the p values will not be uniformly distributed under the null hypothesis any more, so you either need to find their new distribution (e.g., through simulation) or interpret them differently.